# WinPhone 8.1 TimeSpan formatting output

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have this `ComleteLocation` method that is like a checkout function.

It works, however I can't seem to format the output. I cant do it in XAML because stringformat is not supported.

I would like the output to screen via XAML binding to be ("HH:mm") because I need to know how long I worked at that customer for instance.

```
public async void CompleteLocation(Log log)
{
    int index = _Log.IndexOf(log);
    _Log[index].CheckOut = DateTime.Now;
    TimeSpan LoggedTime = log.CheckOut - log.CheckIn;

    log.LoggedTime = LoggedTime;
    log.NotifyPropertyChanged("CheckOut");
    log.NotifyPropertyChanged("LoggedTime");
    await saveLogDataAsync();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use your own StringConverter... It comes down to doing:

```
return String.Format((string)parameter, value);
```

and using like this

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding LoggedTime, 
                  Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter}, 
                  ConverterParameter='{}{0:HH:mm}'}" />
```

[Blog post by Marco Minerva.](http://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/04/26/stringformat-converter-for-windows-store-apps/)